# Automatically import all db tables in manage.py shell

Tags: django

Is there a snippet or easy way to import all of my django tables when entering the prompt?

For example, usually my commands go something like this:

```
>>> from userprofile.models import Table
>>> Table.objects...
```

This way, as soon as I entered the prompt, I'd already have the tables imported. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) adds the [`shell_plus`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py) command for `manage.py` which does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import get_models
for _class in get_models():
    globals()[_class.__name__] = _class
```

Here you end up with all installed models available globally, refering to them with their class name. Read the docs for `django.db.models.get_models` for more info:

> Definition: get_models(self, app_mod=None, include_auto_created=False, include_deferred=False)
>   Docstring:
>    Given a module containing models, returns a list of the models.
>    Otherwise returns a list of all installed models.
>
> By default, auto-created models (i.e., m2m models without an
>    explicit intermediate table) are not included. However, if you
>    specify include_auto_created=True, they will be.
>
> By default, models created to satisfy deferred attribute
>    queries are *not* included in the list of models. However, if
>    you specify include_deferred, they will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
...   module = __import__(app)
...   globals()[module.__name__] = module
...
```

You'll get the fully qualified names though; `userprofile.models.Table` instead of `Table`.